# Versioning per different project (feed) in Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, versioning, azure-artifacts

I have a .Net Core repo, that consists of various smaller projects, and a pipeline that builds it, tests it, and publishes the nugets on the feed.
My problem is that all different nugets that get published have the same version.

What I want to accomplish is to have for each nuget published a different version according to how it is developed/pushed (I cannot just split the repo). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pack the project on by one:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: 'ConsoleAppCore/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 2
    minorVersion: 1
    patchVersion: 1

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: 'ConsoleAppCore/ConsoleAppCore/ConsoleAppCore.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 3
    minorVersion: 1
    patchVersion: 1

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: 'ConsoleAppCore/ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: 1
    minorVersion: 1
    patchVersion: 1
```

Comment: Will this approach work when the projects are dependent to each other?

Comment: You could try to pack the project on by one, and specify the version. Check my updated reply.